# how to get all Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY and phone number size onece

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I want to get all contact name along with phone number size in it.
Now I am using tow queries:

1.

```
crContacts = getContentResolver()
            .query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null)
```

and then
2.

```
while (crContacts.moveToNext()) {
id = crContacts.getString(crContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
Cursor crPhones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

}
```

Any way to get `phone number size` and  `Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY` once without query twice?

Comment: Need more details related to the database as it is not clear from your question. Also you can add extra tags related to database.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts use this database

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by phone number **size**, but you can easily access all `Phone.CONTENT_URI` fields along with implicit joins from the `Contacts.CONTENT_URI` table, here's an example:

```
String[] projection = new String[] { Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };
Cursor c = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,null);
while (c.moveToNext()) {
   long contactId = c.getLong(0);
   String name = c.getString(1);
   String phone = c.getString(2);
   Log.i("Phones", "got contact phone: " + contactId + " - " + name + " - " + phone);
}
```

You can read more about the implicit joins you get when querying any Data table here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data#columns